# What would be the approach to drawing 3d graphics in android?

Tags: java, android, 3d

In regular Java never-mind android, you could use a JPanel or some 3d engine or library to draw your graphics. I am making a 3d game in android and the best solution i could find was creating a new activity and filling it with a surface view. But I am new to android and I based my opinion fully on this line of the android forums: `Provides a dedicated drawing surface` Though recently I've heard that Surface Views are resource thirsty. How would I go about drawing 3d graphics in android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

Comment: For games i'm using LibGDX: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: is that an android library or just java

Comment: since I'm new to android I'm straying away from libraries.

Comment: Well then: http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

Comment: well SurfaceView is in the right ballpark

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question it is a GLSurfaceView that you want.